# Creating an extensible iOS view

Tags: ios, uiview, charts, uiscrollview

I am trying to create an application that lets user(s) create or update an org chart. Specifically any node can be extended in any direction. I am new to UI development and so am stuck as to which view to use. Is a UIScrollView sufficient for this? The functionalities I want to code in are -

1. Able to scroll in any direction.
2. Able to zoom in and zoom out to see different levels of the chart.
3. Able to save the position and zoom level that user is in so that I can start there the next time the app is opened (of course this is not as important).

It did not look like core-plot would give me this option. May be I am wrong.

Comment: Yes - a standard scroll view can do this although you will have to code the org chart functionality. You will also have to save info like the scroll position and zoom level. From the documentation: `The UIScrollView class provides support for displaying content that is larger than the size of the application’s window. It enables users to scroll within that content by making swiping gestures, and to zoom in and back from portions of the content by making pinching gestures.`. Link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview

Comment: Thanks! I will write the code for the chart. I will look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** UIScrollView has methods to handle these functionalities and you can save your zoom level and scroll position in **NSUserDefaults** so you can access data later.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview